# what does "data: DataFrame" do in python after class definition

Tags: python

For example the code is like

```
class RankingFeatureDataset(Dataset):
    data: DataFrame
    def __post_init__(self):
```

I am wondering what "data:DataFrame" do in this code. It seems it is a kind of way for constructor. Thank you.

Comment: It indicates that the attribute `data` of the class and its instances is a `DataFrame`

Comment: Thank very very much for reply. Do you know where to find the official docs to explain this kind of definition. Thanks

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/

Answer (score 3):

The `data: DataFrame` is the type hinting syntax.

Since python is a dynamically typed language, that is, there is not an associated type with variables, type hinting is to indicate the type of the variable.

Usually it is used in function definitions, for example:

```py
def foo(bar: int) -> int:
    print(bar)
    bat: int = bar + 1
    return bat
```

`bar: int`, `-> int` , and `bat: int = bar + 1` are all type hints. However, they are only an indication, or a “hint” as to say, so even if you pass in a variable of the “wrong” type, the code would still run.

In this case, as @kindall has said, it is to indicate that `data` is of type `DataFrame`. You can learn more about type hints [here](https://realpython.com/lessons/type-hinting/).